# Spatie/ Laravel-translation Not displaying required answer

Tags: laravel

```
public function index() { 
$newsItem = Page::findOrFail(5); 
$translations = [ 'en' => 'Hello', 'fr' => 'Bonjour', 'de' => 'Hallo', ]; $newsItem->setTranslations('desc', $translations);  
return $newsItem->getTranslations('desc', ['en', 'fr']); 
}
```

Here, it show all three translation data ...expecting to show just two..i.e `'en'=>'Hello', 'fr'=>'Bonjur'`

Comment: Where can someone find the class Page in this line of code: 'newsItem = Page::findOrFail(5); ' ? Maybe Page is a model created.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.